# Multiplying inverse of vector matrix with meshgrid for rendering triangle?

Tags: matrices, triangles

What does it mean when I multiply a inverse of matrix consisting of vectors representing 2 sides of triangle along with the coordinates meshgrid (which is generated in numpy). To be specific lets say triangle has 3 points X, Y, Z. M is matrix containing vectors (Y - X) and (Z - X) so it has size (2, 2). We find inverse of M and call it M_hat. Then M_hat is multiplied by meshgrid of size (2, n^2) (reshaped from 2 x n x n) where n is any number.
Is this transforming my coordinates axes? I am not clear what is geometric interpretation of this and the intuition. 
This is intermediate step of triangle rendering algorithm and I am finding it bit difficult to understand. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried working out and drawing a couple of examples yourself?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I tried to work on small example still I dont get the intuition behind taking inverse of those vectors. What exactly are we trying to solve by taking that inverse?

Comment: I also understood that we are doing similar thing to change of basis inverse. What is intuition behind this change of basis especially for rendering the triangle?